# How to apply pattern in conditional if else?

Tags: java, design-patterns, conditional-statements

My goal is to avoid using Else as I always do in Javascript code

In the example below, is there a solution?

```
public void initView() {
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewService.class));

    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            initView();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: _My goal is to avoid using Else..._ Actually the goal should be to avoid any `if` or `switch` conditions e.g. by using the power of  interfaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just return early.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            initView();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But I see no problem with the code as written.  If you took a look at the Java API source code would would see many if/else constructs written by well respected computer scientists.

Comment: I understand. The "super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);" can be called before the if ?

Comment: Yes it can, if that is what you want.  But then it will always be executed which is not what your original code did.  But typically that is when the overridden method is usually called.  And if you do it that way,you won't need the explicit return.

Comment: Following this pattern you can also put a return inside inner if and remove the inner else. No?

Comment: @muasif80 Yes  you could.  I thought about doing that but I did not want to clutter up the answer after I made my point.